# How to set the value of multiple arrays at the same time in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

**Schema**

```
"_id" : ObjectId(""),
"top_level_array" : [
    {
        "array_one" : [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4",
            "5"
        ],
        "name" : "user name",
        "array_two" : [
            "1",
            "2"
        ],
        "array_three" : [
            "1",
            "2"
        ]
    },
    {
    // another document 
    },
    {
    // another document
    }
]
```

**Question**

I can successfully set the value of a single array with:

```
db.users.update({email_addr:"email@email.com", "top_level_array.name":"user name"},{$set:{"top_level_array.$.array_one":["just one value now"]}})
```

How can I set the value of multiple arrays at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

Separate the different arrays to update with a comma eg:

```
db.users.update({email_addr:"email@email.com", "top_level_array.name":"user name"},{$set:{"top_level_array.$.array_one":["just one value now"],"top_level_array.$.array_two":["another value"]}})
```

And to clarify the context of this solution, the query is conditional in that it searches for a match on `name` within a document, and then updates arrays that are at the same level as `name` ie `array_one` and `array_two`.